# watir webdriver "no such session: title\n"message when doing a Browser.new :chrome

Tags: watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get off the ground with Watir Webdriver and I need it to work with Chrome. I downloaded the chromedriver and added it to my path but when I do this (in irb, using a mac):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

I get this message:

```
<Watir::Browser:0x..fb07a5a545bf96f92 url={"message"=>"no such session: url\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=0.7,platform=Mac OS X 10.7.5 x86_64)"} title={"message"=>"no such session: title\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=0.7,platform=Mac OS X 10.7.5 x86_64)"}>
```

If I omit the ":chrome" part it will open up a new firefox browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am running on a mac with OSX v10.8.3 and have no problem launching chrome.   So maybe the problem is something related to a version, or maybe your path addition was not perm?   I'd do two things.  from command line do "gem list" and let us know versions of watir, webdriver, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in `ChromeDriver2 v0.7 (r192977)`. You can just downgrade to `ChromeDriver2 v0.5 beta (March 26th)` and it should solve your problem.

All the versions are [available here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list).

Worked great for me under Ruby 1.9.3 32-bit, running on a Win7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

If your using a Mac, just do a brew install of chromedriver on your command line.
    brew install chromedriver

You may need to set your Mac up first, just go to this link and follow instructions to install homebrew.
    http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

This is the easiest way to install chromedriver to your path and works like a charm.